# Husky + lint-staged not working on Windows (command not found)

Tags: javascript, npm, hook, husky, lint-staged

I cannot seem to get `husky` and `lint-staged` to work on my Windows 10 machine.

Currently my setup is as follows:

*.huskyrc.json*

```
{
  "hooks": {
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
  }
}
```

*.lintstagedrc* (though it seems not to matter whats in here since the problem appears to occur before this file is even read)

```
{
  "**/*.+(js|md)": [
    "prettier --write",
    "eslint --fix src/",
    "git add"
  ]
}
```

*package.json*

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --watchAll=false",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint-fix": "eslint . --fix"
  },
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "husky": "^4.3.0",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.4",
    ...
  }
```

I am using npm version 6.14.11 and node version 14.15.1.

Now, when I enter `git add .` and `git commit -m "test"` in the console this is the result:

```
husky > pre-commit (node v14.15.1)
C:\Program Files\nodejs/node_modules/node/bin/node: line 1: This: command not found
husky > pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)
```

This appears to only happen on my Windows machine and does not seem to be a problem on Ubuntu. What could be going on here?

Comment: Have you installed prettier? I think lint-staged need it

Comment: prettier 2.1.2 is installed

Answer (score 1):

If you installed `lint-staged` locally, then you need to prepend the path to `lint-staged`.

*.huskyrc.json*

```json
{
  "hooks": {
    "pre-commit": "./node_modules/.bin/lint-staged"
  }
}
```

Another way is to add a script to your *package.json* that runs `lint-staged`.

*package.json*

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "lint-staged": "lint-staged"
  }
}
```

Then modify your `pre-commit` hook.

*.huskyrc.json*

```json
{
  "hooks": {
    "pre-commit": "npm lint-staged"
  }
}
```

Of course, you could also choose to install `lint-staged` globally, in which case, you shouldn’t need to make any changes. Just run: `npm install -g lint-staged`